# Plugin effect added on a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a hidden div.

```
<div id="hello" style="display: none;">Hello</div>
```

How can I add some graph that is generated by jQuery, i.e.

```
$('#hello').booklet();
```

won't work because of the element being hidden and DOM doesn't work like I want too.

Answer (score 0):

Display it first then add the plugin:
`$('#hello').show().booklet();`